# Using jQuery to replace tags within an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to Javascript and JQuery and I am trying to replace all my  tags with  upon first click, and then replace with  on the second click, and so forth.

Basically just cycling through them so on each click I have a 3d rendered box or sphere. I tried to run it with this code however it does not work.

When I checked the console, only the  lines were getting logged, so it doesn't seem to be replacing them correctly. I need to keep the tags within each preserved as I work.

```
var counter = 0;
var myArr = ["a-sphere", "a-box"];

$("#targeted").click(function() {
  if(counter == myArr.length) counter = 0;
  $(myArr[counter]).replaceWith(function() {
    var myString = "<" + myArr[counter] + ">" + $(this).html() + "</" + myArr[counter] + ">";
    console.log(myString + counter);
    return myString;
  });
  counter++;
});
```

Comment: Your messing with [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)... Look for [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) and the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

Comment: In short, that is `$([static element selector]).on([event(s) coma separated],[eventual child selector],function(){ // whatever... });`